# Are all commitment schemes pseudo-random functions?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, commitments

I am interested in understanding whether or not we can use commitment schemes that are both hiding and binding as pseudorandom functions.

My reasoning is that if a commitment is hiding, then an attacker cannot distinguish between two commitments. Does this imply that a commitment is also indistinguishable from randomness? hence that commitment schemes are also pseudo random functions?

More concretely, can one use pedersen commitments as pseudo random functions?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In general, clearly no. Take any commitment scheme and build a new one that just appends 100 zeros to the commitment and ignores them. It's trivial to see that neither binding nor hiding is impacted, but it's trivial to distinguish a commitment from a random value.

Comment: You'd have to define how exactly you would define the pseudorandom function based on Pedersen commitments. If you just use `r`, the Pedersen randomness, as the pseudorandom function key, then this will not be a random function provided that `g` and `h` are known. Specifically querying for `f_r(0)` will reveal `h^r` after which point all subsequent values can be predicted.

Comment: what if r is public? if h^r is public, how can you predict what is my g^x?